# Wrong use of the unique definition of 'anticipate' (as in 'forestall')?

Tags: word-usage

> [OALD:](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/anticipate?q=anticipate) 4. **anticipate somebody (doing something)** (formal)
>   = to do something before it can be done by somebody else
>   [S]ynonym[:] [forestall](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/forestall)
>   ● When Scott reached the South Pole he found that Amundsen had **anticipated** him.

Please beware that I ask only about this definition unique to **anticipate**. The use of the others [that overlap with 'expect'](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/111885/50720) are decried on p 53, *Plain Words*, 2014, by Ernest Gowers, revised by Rebecca Gowers.

Amundsen reached the South pole [on 14 December 1911](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roald_Amundsen); so it preceded [Scott's arrival](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Falcon_Scott) on 17 January 1912. But the fact remains that Scott still arrived there; so how did Amundsen **anticipate** (= forestall) Scott?

Comment: Amundsen prevented Scott from being the **first** to arrive at the pole, which was the glory point of the expedition.

Comment: I don't see the objection. "to do something before it can be done by somebody else". Amundson reached the pole before Scott could do it. The quoted definition does not mean "forestall", which means to prevent something from happening.

Comment: Only one expedition could be *first*. As @StoneyB implied, once Amundsen had reached the pole, Scott was prevented from being first... he was "frozen out" of first place.

Comment: anticipated=beat him to it

Answer (score 2):

I think the definition *"to do something before it can be done by somebody else"* is poor in that it's slightly mixing up two actual usages, and not being quite right on either.

From http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anticipate, we have

*to be before (another) in doing, thinking, achieving, etc.*

but this is usually used when the achievement is separated by a long time period, so not really suitable for Scott / Amundsen, and it doesn't have the connotation of 'preventing' the second action.

We also have

*to nullify, prevent, or forestall by taking countermeasures in advance*

but this usually has some of the flavour of 'expect', in that there has to be some merit to predicting what would happen. As Scott's expedition wasn't a secret, there's no particular merit in the prediction. If talking about a race, you don't normally say that the winner "anticipated" the second-placed competitor.

It's possible that Amundsen could have anticipated some other aspect of the Scott expedition, but that's not clear from the example.